# How to make same margins in the different browser? UL margins

Tags: css

UL element margins same but Firefox and IE showing different.

[image]

[image]

FULL CODE:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body
            {
                background-color: Red;
            }
            ul
            {
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 8pt;
            }
            ul a
            {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: Black;
            }
            ul a:hover
            {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            table
            {
                background-color: Transparent;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table tr td
            {
                vertical-align: top;
                text-align: left;
                font: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            #tblYayinAkisi
            {
                border: 1px white solid;
                background-color: #222222;
                font-family: Verdana;
                color: #ffffff;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 10pt;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #tblYayinAkisi th
            {
                background-color: Transparent;
                background-image: url(../images/bckSiyahGriTram.png);
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                height: 20px;
                padding-left: 10px;
            }
            #tblYayinAkisi td
            {
                background-color: #222222;
            }
            #tblYayinAkisi td ul
            {
                border: 1px white solid;
                width: 100%;
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
            #tblYayinAkisi td ul li
            {
                clear: both;
                padding-top: 7px;
                list-style: none;
            }
            #tblYayinAkisi td ul li b
            {
                margin-right: 10px;
                float: left;
            }
            #tblYayinAkisi td ul li a
            {
                color: #ffffff;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="tblYayinAkisi">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        YABAN'da bugün
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li><b>00:00</b><a target="_blank" href="programlar.aspx?id=24">TROFE ODASI</a></li>
                            <li><b>01:00</b><a target="_blank" href="programlar.aspx?id=17">YERLİ YABAN</a></li>
                            <li><b>01:30</b><a target="_blank" href="programlar.aspx?id=16">HEDEF</a></li>
                            <li><b>02:00</b><a target="_blank" href="programlar.aspx?id=28">İZCİ</a></li>
                            <li><b>02:30</b><a target="_blank" href="programlar.aspx?id=4">KUŞLAR</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <img src="images/canliYayin.png" />
                            <img src="images/tumAkis.png" />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [`padding`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) on the `ul` as well. E.g.

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Most browsers comes with default margins/paddings on certain block elements, slightly similar this one: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

Comment: Oh, here's a more comprehensive link: http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your first `ul` declaration:

```
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none }
```

You will need to adjust your other `ul` declaration (i.e. `margin-left: 10px`) to suit your needs, but this rule will zero it out the differences.

The reason is that each browser uses a different combination of `padding` and `margin` to indent the `ul`. By zeroing out both, and setting only one (i.e. `padding` *or* `margin`) you can keep the display consistent.

Additionally, you need to use a valid `DOCTYPE` in your code so modern browsers don't revert to Quirks mode. Something like this goes at the very top of your HTML file with NOTHING in front of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```